# replacing stopword from string java, how to handle first character

Tags: java, regex

Hey I am doing a project in which I have to remove the stopwords (or rather certain words, i have a list of about 560 of them) from tweets,I was using below code :

```
tweet= tweet.replaceAll(' '+stopword+' ', "");
```

But here is problem as first word can also be stopword, so how to handle if first word of the tweet is a stopword, if u are thinking

```
text = text.replaceAll(stopword+' ', "");
```

Then this wont work because some stopwords are ending characters of a word, so please give a solution for these. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the word break boundary matcher:

```
"\\b" + Pattern.quote(stopword) + "\\b"
```

This matches word breaks, which includes spaces, start/end of string, punctuation etc. See the doc for java.util.Pattern for more details.

I also put in that the stopword should be quoted, since it looks like a variable, and thus shouldn't be trusted to contain a valid regex.

Comment: Note that \\b may not work well with non-ASCII characters; or has this been implemented in Java? For JavaScript I needed to create my own pseudo-word boundaries using custom character classes to work with Scandinavian words that sometimes start/end in letters like æøåöä.

Comment: @Eirik sounds entirely plausible that there may be problems like that with it. Caveat emptor, I guess.

Comment: Actually, it seems to work! [link](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) That's the first time I've seen that. Go, Java!

Comment: thanks above code works, meanwhile i solved by making a string by joining all tokens which are not a stopword :)